# pysaml2 - AuthnContextClassRef, PasswordProtectedTransport

Tags: python, saml

I am struggling to understand how to configure pysaml2 and add the AuthnContext in my request.
I have a SP and I would need to add the following request when the client performs the login request:

```
<samlp:RequestedAuthnContext> 
<saml:AuthnContextClassRef>
urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:PasswordProtectedTransport
</saml:AuthnContextClassRef> 
</samlp:RequestedAuthnContext>
```

I am struggling because I tried everything I could and I believe that it is possible to add that in my requests because in here https://github.com/IdentityPython/pysaml2/blob/master/src/saml2/samlp.py

I can see:

```
AUTHN_PASSWORD = "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:Password"
AUTHN_PASSWORD_PROTECTED = \
    "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:PasswordProtectedTransport"
```

I just do not know how to reference that.. I have a simple configuration like this:

```
"service": {
        "sp": {
            "name": "BLABLA",
            "allow_unsolicited": true,
            "want_response_signed": false,
            "logout_requests_signed": true,
            "endpoints": {
                "assertion_consumer_service": ["https://mywebste..."],
                "single_logout_service": [["https://mywebste...", "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect"]]
            },
            "requestedAuthnContext" : true
        }
    }
```

Anyone know how to add the above config?
I struggle to understand how to  build the config dictionary, even by reading their docs. Any ideas?
I am happy to add the "PasswordProtectedTransport" directly in the code if the config does not allow that.. But I am not sure how to do it.

Thanks,
R

Comment: Folks I solved my issue. Thanks anyway.

Comment: would be great if you could post the solution as well

Answer (score 0):

At some point your client calls `create_authn_request(...)`
(or `prepare_for_authenticate(...)`,
or `prepare_for_negotiated_authenticate(...)`).
You should pass the extra arg `requested_authn_context`.

The `requested_authn_context` is an object of type `saml2.samlp.RequestedAuthnContext` that contains the wanted `AuthnContextClassRef`.

```py
...

from saml2.saml import AUTHN_PASSWORD_PROTECTED
from saml2.saml import AuthnContextClassRef
from saml2.samlp import RequestedAuthnContext


requested_authn_context = RequestedAuthnContext(
    authn_context_class_ref=[
        AuthnContextClassRef(AUTHN_PASSWORD_PROTECTED),
    ],
    comparison="exact",
)
req_id, request = create_authn_request(
    ...,
    requested_authn_context=requested_authn_context,
)
```